# Redirect from an https sub-directory to a separate https domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I'm trying to do the following... either through an apache 2 conf directive or .htaccess.

Two sites:
1) www.myfirstsite.com
2) www.my99thsite.com

I want to redirect in the following way and I'm not sure exactly what needs to happen with certs and redirects:

When a user visits https://www.myfirstsite.com/mysubdir I want to redirect him to https://www.my99thsite.com.

mysubdir is just an empty directory.

Thanks-

-KR

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/]) https://www.my99thsite.com [R]
```

This will check whether the directory is exist. If it will redirect to https://www.my99thsite.com. This should be in your www.myfirstsite.com .htaccess